# google apps script - как подтягивать данные из таблицы для webhook?

Tags: telegram-bot, google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet, webhook

Вопрос: какой код можно прописать, чтобы бот сравнивал команду запрос в столбце "А" google таблицы и отправлял ответ из этой строки, но из столбца "B"), чтобы не хранить вопросы и ответ в самом скрипте?
UPD: Задачу решил всем спасибо, заодно сделал хранение переменных в самой таблице:

```
// configuration
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetSetup = ss.getSheetByName("setup");
var botVer = sheetSetup.getRange(2,3).getValue();
var sheetBot = ss.getSheetByName(botVer);
var apiToken = sheetSetup.getRange(3,3).getValue();
var appToken = sheetSetup.getRange(4,3).getValue();
var baza = sheetSetup.getRange(5,3).getValue();
var info =  sheetSetup.getRange(6,3).getValue();
var error =  sheetSetup.getRange(7,3).getValue();
var apiUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot"+apiToken;
var appUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/"+appToken+"/exec";

    // set webhook
    function setWebhook(){
      var url = apiUrl + "/setwebhook?url="+appUrl;
      var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
      Logger.log(res);
    }
    
    
    // handle webhook
    function doPost(e){
      var webhookData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
      var from = webhookData.message.from.id;
      var text = webhookData.message.text;
      
      var findAsk = sheetBot.getRange(baza).getValues();
      
      var row;
      for(let i =0;i < findAsk.length;i++){
        if(findAsk[i].indexOf(text)!== -1){
          row = i+1;
          break;
          }
          else row = error;
        }

      var ask = sheetBot.getRange(row,info).getValue();

      var sendText = encodeURIComponent(ask);
    
      var url  = apiUrl+"/sendmessage?parse_mode=HTML&chat_id="+from+"&text="+sendText;
      var opts = {"muteHttpExceptions": true}
      UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, opts).getContentText();
    }
    
    
    function doGet(e){
      return ContentService.createTextOutput("Method GET not allowed");
    }
```

Comment: Андрей, тоже интересует вопрос отправления через запрос в телеграм-боте в колонках А и Б. Можете, если это возможно, дать ссылку на итоговый год и обезличенную таблицу? Спасибо.

Comment: найдите меня в телеге @workdao - сброшу получившийся вариант альфы и бета версии

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы вытащить значения определённой ячейки можно использовать следующий код:

```
function get(x) { 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var question = sheet.getRange('A' + x).getDisplayValues();
  var ask = sheet.getRange('B' + x).getDisplayValues();

  return question + '\n' + ask;

}

sendText(1, get(3));
```

функция `sendText` отправляет сообщение от имени Телеграмм бота указанному пользователю:

```
function sendText(tlgrm_id, text) {
  UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + tlgrm_id + '&text=' + encodeURIComponent(text));
}
```

таким образом бот пришлёт содержимое ячеек А и B переданной строки в качестве аргумента `get()`

Comment: спасибо, попробую разобраться и применить...

Comment: Если ответ решает ваш вопрос, пожалуйста отметьте его таковым это поможет другим пользователям.

Comment: к сожалению пока не смог это применить под свою задачу. В моем варианте необходимо прислать команду, найти эту команду в столбце А и отправить обратно ответ содержащийся в этой строке но из  столбца B.

Comment: Дополните свой ответ кодом получившимся на основе ответа

Comment: входе долгих попыток получилось сделать то, что требовалось, но видимо всё-равно есть ошибки - не приходит ответ, если ненайдена строка соответствующая запросу

Comment: Добавьте обработку данного сценария в условие

Comment: спасибо, всё получилось